# Evaluate string from user to comma separated words string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string given by user in the following form:

```
"single, single, double word, single  word, also      single"
```

How I can parse this string to obtain string of comma separated words, where each not single whitespace is treated as a separator and replaced with `','`, and each single is replaced with `%20` ? So the result would be:

```
"single,single,double%20word,single,word,also,single"
```

? can I do it in one step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you ask:

```
def repl(m):
  if m.group(0) == ' ':
    return '%20'
  else:
    return ','

re.sub(',? +', repl, "single, single, double word, single  word, also      single")
```

However, if your goal is to end up with proper URL escaping I'd advise that you actually use a library function designed to do that. eg: `urllib.quote`

Comment: unfortunately it must be in this specific form

Answer (score 0):

You probably could do it in a single step, but it would be safer to do it in two.
First use a regex to replace `\s\s+` with `,`
Then replace `\s` with `%20`

Comment: Good point, missed that one. That should be done first, with `\s+,\s+`